# Считывание из файла и отправка данных на вход программы omxplayer

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Суть в том, чтобы давать на вход программе путь с видеофайлом. 
В итоге получился вот такой код, но не корректно работает.

```
#!/bin/sh    
SERVICE="/usr/bin/omxplayer"
file="/home/pi/Documents/list.txt"
        while read line; do
                while ps ax | grep -v grep | grep omxplayer; do sleep 1s; done
                $SERVICE -b $line
        done <$file
```

Программа один раз берет на вход путь к файлу, проигрывает, а потом вываливается с сообщением

```
stack smashing detected /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin terminated
/usr/bin/omxplayer: line 67: 4873 Aborted
PLAYER_LIBS${LD_LIBRARY_PATH: +:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" $OMXPLAYER_BIN "$@"
```

Comment: [stack smashing detected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1345670/4827341)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, я в принципе осознал что это за проблема, но впервые с ней сталкиваюсь, и не знаю что делать. Как её решить?

Comment: Первое, используйте *pgrep*. Второе, ещё лучше используйте *waitpid*. Ну и третье, проблема судя по всему где-то внутри самого проигрывателя или библиотек, с которыми он собран.